# verify mail in flutter with firebase

Tags: flutter

I have a login which works through Firebase, I am implementing the logic so that the email is verified after creating the account[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qGPD. jpg)mail arrives successfully [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tmke.jpg) and is verified successfully.[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Xf4 .png)account is created successfully
but the app does not take the change and does not send me to the next screen

I tried using chatgpt, I'm new to flutter but I can't figure out how to solve it.
Ok, I'm going to share the repository and more complete information with you:
User registration flow:
The user enters their email, password, and password confirmation on the SignUpScreen screen.
The _signUpLogic.signUpWithEmailAndPassword function is called to register the user.
If the registration is successful, a verification email is sent to the user and they navigate to the EmailVerificationPage screen.
The user must verify their email by clicking on the sent link.
Once the email is verified, the user is redirected to the CreateUser screen to complete their profile. git repo: https://github.com/CentenoDev/ITWANA-APP/tree/master

Comment: share your code to get more clarity on what happens while success msg is shown